# Velociraptor escape

Tags: geometry

This is a mock test problem from [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/135/).

[image]

I think that he should run at the angle bisecting two of the dinosaurs, but then again, one is wounded.

Comment: Don't move! They won't see you! ...that's how it works right?

Comment: See one solution [here](http://www.mbeckler.org/velociraptors/).

Comment: It's important to note that the other raptors' top speed is 25 m/s